# Installing RubyPress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wordpress, rubypress

I want to use RubyPress in my project. I've been reading [the documentation](https://github.com/zachfeldman/rubypress), and it says that I need to:

1. Install the gem using `gem install rubypress`.
2. Add "rubypress" to my gem file.
3. In a script `require 'rubypress'`.

I am not sure where to add `require 'rubypress'`, also I do not know if by doing the installation it should make a class or if I have to create one class and then continue with the process.

I need it so that a user can make or edit the posts on WordPress and then the posts can be viewed on my website.

I hope that someone can help me with that.

Comment: The "in a script" part pertains to non-Rails operation as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby on Rails' goal is to be as simple as possible coming out of the box. I have no indication of how far along into the process you are, so I'll start from the beginning.

To be a little more explicit on zachfeldman's instructions:

## Checking Your Install:

### Installing `rubypress`

In a terminal/command line shell, type `gem install rubypress`. This will either work, or it will fail. If you get something like `gem: Command not found.` it means you don't have gem, or maybe even ruby installed. You will need to go to https://rubygems.org/pages/download and go from there.

If you get back `ERROR:  could not find gem rubypress locally or in a repository` check your spelling, then your internet settings.

Otherwise, rubypress should install nicely.

### Adding `rubypress` to your bundler

In your `[path to your app]/gemfile` add the line: `gem 'rubypress'`. This should allow you to now access the gem from anywhere inside of your ruby application. If this doesn't exist, you'll need to build a ruby app.

### Inside a Script

Anywhere you want to use `rubypress`, likely a lot of places, you simply add `require 'rubypress'` to the top of the file, and that should help you get the rubypress functions you need.

Feel free to comment on where you get stuck, I'll help you walk through. The more details, the better.

~POS

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please look at how you've formatted your answer and compare it to the common look. Instead of using headers to mark sections, it's standard to format in a more familiar, less formal style. Also, on Stack Overflow we don't use salutations, valedictions or signatures (your "`~POS`"). Also, comments are more for incidental information, if the OP has additional questions those should be asked in a separate question rather than a continuous stream of comments.

Comment: Thanks, I already did that, and think that is working. Now I'm trying "pull' or "get" the posts that I make on WP to the my app and then I'll see if it is working. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

If you are on a Rails project:

1. Add `gem 'rubypress'` to your Gemfile.
2. Run `bundle install`.
3. It should be auto-required and no `require` should be needed. Use it.

The `require` statement is intended for external usage only (non-Rails).

Comment: Rails uses `bundler` which reads the gems files and handles the environment for you, auto-requiring any gems in the gem file... So, `bundler` is the one doing the heavy lifting for you - Just to give credit where credit is due ;-)

Comment: Thanks for that @Myst :)